# Installfest| Railsbridge|Deploy a Rails app|heroku push Rejected| Failed to Install Gem via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, installation

Really stuck on Step 2.5: Deploy (push) to heroku - (http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/deploy_a_rails_app). I have done as requested. Yet the expected result does not match. The issue persists even though I have tried all the solutions from similar posts. I have altered SQLite to "pg". Installed postgresq1. Yet to no avail. Either SQLite gems are detected which I have not been able to locate on the file. Please pardon, the lack of understanding I have at this stage.

```
C:\Sites\test_app>git commit -m "Updates for heroku deployment"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\Sites\test_app>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 96, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (88/88), done.
Writing objects: 100% (96/96), 21.53 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 96 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Resolving dependencies....
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing rake 11.1.2
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160610-323-o54ilu.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Resolving dependencies....
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing rake 11.1.2
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Installing rack 1.6.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Installing arel 6.0.3
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.22
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.5
remote:
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:
remote:        /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160610-323-o54ilu.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.6.0
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to agile-spire-70127.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/agile-spire-70127.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/agile-spire-70127.git'
```

Heroku Build log:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies....
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing rake 11.1.2
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing minitest 5.9.0
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing sass 3.4.22
       Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
       Installing tilt 2.0.5
       Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160610-323-o54ilu.rb extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       extconf failed, exit code 1
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing rdoc 4.2.2
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
       Installing uglifier 3.0.0
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing sprockets 3.6.0
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies....
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing rake 11.1.2
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing minitest 5.9.0
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing sass 3.4.22
       Installing sqlite3 1.3.11 with native extensions
       Installing tilt 2.0.5

       Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160610-323-o54ilu.rb extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
       'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
       and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

       extconf failed, exit code 1

       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_6045ed930dd6a5b85911b00009c2001c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/sqlite3-1.3.11/gem_make.out
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing rdoc 4.2.2
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
       Installing uglifier 3.0.0
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing sprockets 3.6.0
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
       continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Gemfile.local

```
Gemfile.local
gem 'activerecord-postgresql-adapter
```

Thank You! I made the changes as suggested yet still have issues though it has been deployed. Which may be the cause of a 404 when opening the app. I have added 2.2.4 ruby to Gemfile & deleted Gem.lock.

```
\test_app>git push heroku master
 objects: 101, done.
mpression using up to 2 threads.
ing objects: 100% (93/93), done.
objects: 100% (101/101), 22.60 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
1 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
Compressing source files... done.
Building source:

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies....
       Installing rake 11.2.2
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing minitest 5.9.0
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Using bundler 1.11.2
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Installing sass 3.4.22
       Installing tilt 2.0.5
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
       Installing rdoc 4.2.2
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing uglifier 3.0.0
       Installing sprockets 3.6.0
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
       Installing activesupport 4.2.5.1
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing mail 2.6.4
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing globalid 0.3.6
       Installing activemodel 4.2.5.1
       Installing jbuilder 2.5.0
       Installing activejob 4.2.5.1
       Installing activerecord 4.2.5.1
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
       Installing loofah 2.0.3
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing actionview 4.2.5.1
       Installing actionpack 4.2.5.1
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.5.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.0.4
       Installing railties 4.2.5.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
       Installing jquery-rails 4.1.1
       Installing rails 4.2.5.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.4
       Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
       Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (30.83s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2016-06-16T15:01:23.677344 #1026]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d5245f6cdcdd591d927b90b3ee05e2bc/public/assets/application-b0426e496058d3d784915d30693e0d86e3f1908fa66e11169e89ec
       I, [2016-06-16T15:01:23.677998 #1026]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d5245f6cdcdd591d927b90b3ee05e2bc/public/assets/application-b0426e496058d3d784915d30693e0d86e3f1908fa66e11169e89ec

       I, [2016-06-16T15:01:23.709388 #1026]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d5245f6cdcdd591d927b90b3ee05e2bc/public/assets/application-0723cb9a2dd5a514d954f70e0fe0b89f6f9f1ae3a375c182f43b5f

       I, [2016-06-16T15:01:23.709596 #1026]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d5245f6cdcdd591d927b90b3ee05e2bc/public/assets/application-0723cb9a2dd5a514d954f70e0fe0b89f6f9f1ae3a375c182f43b5f

       Asset precompilation completed (4.30s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean

###### WARNING:
       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.2.4'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.

###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing...
       Done: 30.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://agile-spire-70127.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Verifying deploy... done.
://git.heroku.com/agile-spire-70127.git
branch]      master -> master

\test_app>git push heroku master
ng up-to-date
```

To solve Procfile

```
git add .
e replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.
 its original line endings in your working directory.

git commit -m "Procfile"
F will be replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.
 its original line endings in your working directory.

e replaced by CRLF in Gemfile.
 its original line endings in your working directory.
1 insertion(+), 169 deletions(-)
4 Gemfile.lock

git push heroku
 branch master has no upstream branch.
t branch and set the remote as upstream, use

-upstream heroku master
```

Yet no differnce to 404 error.

Comment: can you please list the heroku logs? and are you on master branch? Also can you add your gemfile?

Comment: Heroku log: agile-spire-70127

Comment: That's not the whole log file. Go to your application directory and type in "heroku logs". Add the result in your question.

Comment: Apologies, just getting the hang of how this works. I have placed log in original comment as there appears to be a limit on comments.

Comment: As I mentioned in the first comment please add a gemfile too in the question

Comment: As per master branch, i am not sure. I have just been following the instructions on the install fest. I have done a quick research on what a master branch is. From what i understand. I don't think i am.Yes, please give me a moment as i locate it. :) Thank You !

Comment: run 'git checkout master' , with this command you should be on master branch and then try to push heroku..

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I put the command and it states already on master.  In addition, as i mentioned in the original question i downloaded postgres it was quite a lengthy process and has made its own user on my laptop. Is this normal?

Comment: I am confused as to how their is squlite in the gemfile though i had edited it to pg. I have quite a few gemfiles i will also add them to the original post. It must be from when i was trying to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check Gemfile.rb , Please put your 'sqlite3' in development group like this.

```
group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'     # Use postgresql as the database for Active Record got heroku
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

please delete the Gemfile.lock in you application, please again do bundle install or bundle update.
and push your code on repository and commit done. with new Gemfile.rb and Gemfile.lock also commit .

Then finally do the

```
git push heroku master
```